# Amazon S3 Signature does not match when extra query params "_ga" added in url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-analytics

Trying to download file using s3 pre-signed url. We have integration with google analytics because of that all the hyperlinked is appended with one extra query param, "_ga".

pre-signed url constructed is like `https://someapprouter.herokuapp.com/ant/storage/1619958100/f8c40a75/file?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20fileName%3D%22PersonSampleFormat.csv%22&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190403T191315Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Credential=ACKJOEK2Q%2F20190403%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=xxxx`

But when we are trying to download file from browser the extra query param is getting added which is causing the error in download. Finla URL is like `https://someapprouter.herokuapp.com/ant/storage/1619958100/f8c40a75/file?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20fileName%3D%22PersonSampleFormat.csv%22&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190403T191315Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Credential=AKJOEK2Q%2F20190403%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=xxxx&_ga=yyyyy`

Exception :

> Error>
>   `SignatureDoesNotMatch`
>   
>   The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

How can we exclude query params _ga when s3 is doing signature match.

Comment: I don't think you can. Consider not adding `_ga` to those links.

Comment: looks like we can not exclude. For now I am removing _ga param from pre signed url before redirecting to target.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have autolinker enabled for your GA implementation. To remove it, you need to disable autolinker.

Note, if you're doing cross-domain tracking, then you'll need to customize the autolinker to specific domains, so that the linker will know to only auto link those domains.

If you provide more details of how GA is implemented or provide a link, I can show you specific code.

Comment: Yes, autolinker is enabled for GA implementation and unfortunately I can not disable it. But as you mentioned I will give a try to  customize it for my use case. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can config the linker to only attach the _ga parameters for links to certain domains. In this case, it will be your cross domains, so it will ignore the file server links.